# How I distinguish the merge array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, ios5

I have to 2 NSArray and I merge it into NSMutableArray now I have to distinguish it. How many values in 1 NSArray and 2 also. My problem is that when I got 1 NSArray then I want to show red button before that in table view and 2 array i wnat to show green button. How can i achieve this. I want to show such type of result.

[image]

Comment: Best way is define all the 3 array as public, means create @property of it.

Answer (score 0):

store all values in NSArray as dictionaries with 2 keys - one for the actual object and other for the array type(array1 or array2) and use the same to distinguish the objects in common array

Answer (score 0):

it is better that for combining two array use
        NSMutableDictionary rather than NSMutableArray